# Finding pixel on sprite in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, pixel

In Unity3d we have `RaycastHit.textureCoord` but it doesn't exist anymore in 2D. I was searching about this problem, a lot but I didn't find anything useful.

So I want to know the solution for this problem and I'm wondering why method like textureCoord in 3D doesn't exist in 2D actually in `RaycastHit2D`.

also I want to access to the pixel when mouse cursor on it.

Answer (score 1):

It works in 3D because `RaycastHit.textureCoord` requires a mesh collider. In the 2D case it is way simplee because you can calculate the position yourself as you know the sprite hit, the cursor position and size of the sprite.

Comment: I've used the cursor position and size of the sprite for calculating pixel on sprite but It returned wrong value.

My code :

`pixelX = (int) hitInfo.point.x / 2 * texture.width

pixelY = (int) hitInfo.point.y / 2 * texture.height`

Comment: Can I know what my fault is ?

Comment: @ATHellboy The hit point is in worldspace. Determine the delta of the worldspace position of your sprite to the hitpoint. Then add the offset of your sprite size.  This depends of where the pivot of your sprite is (most likely center).

Comment: I've used this code : `Debug.Log("(" + ((int)((transform.position.x - hitInfo.point.x + transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.mainTextureOffset.x) / 2 * copiedTexture2D.width)) + ", " + ((int)((transform.position.y - hitInfo.point.y + transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.mainTextureOffset.y) / 2 * copiedTexture2D.height)) + ")");`

but like before it returns wrong pixels. for example for top left corner of the 500 * 500 sprite it returns (617, -617)