# Optimization for changing pixels of sprite in Unity3D

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine, sprite, pixel, texture2d

**Problem :**

After a month, I'm coming back to the prototype for painting on sprite for my mini game. As you see in this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732404/painting-sprite-in-unity)** I've figured out the solution for painting on sprite and because of big nested loop in the script, the mini game isn't at the good situation (I mean low FPS). So I've tried to use another method instead of `Texture2D.SetPixel()` then I used `Texture2D.SetPixels()` but like before the FPS was low.

So right now, I don't find any solutions for this problem. Last thing which comes to my mind is **parallel for**.

What do you think, guys ?

**Answer :**

With [PockeTiger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4879026/pocketiger) help as you see. I used `Texture2D.SetPixels` and `Texture2D.GetPixels` for this mini game so for 256 * 256 sprite, The game is almost on 60 FPS and for 512 * 512 sprite, It is on 25 FPS. It's better than use `Texture2D.SetPixel` and `Texture2D.GetPixel` but still It's not good and I need to use OpenGl commands. But this good FPS rather than `Texture2D.SetPixel` It's not just because of using `Texture2D.SetPixels` **It's because, I limit my loop statement to smaller square rather than whole the sprite so order for moving in the loop It's not that much.**

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you have to look out for when you are using SetPixels().

1) First of all if you need to update multiple pixels then never use SetPixel() but SetPixel**s**() instead because that's way better for performance.

2) The Apply() function is also pretty heavy on performance and calling it every frame will draw back your performance a lot as well. If you are looping then be sure to exclude the Apply function from the loop.

```
for(var i:int = 0 ... blahblahblah)
{
 setPixel on i;
}
Apply();
```

3) It also helps a lot if your texturesizes are on the power of 2 (32x32 // 64x64 // 128x128 // 512x512 .... etc.). The SetPixels() and Apply() commands perform way more poorly otherwise.

If you've tried all what I've suggested and the FPS count is still low then you can still try to decrease the size of your textures or look around and experiment with native OpenGL calls which are way faster but require a deep dive into shaders and whatnot.

[Here's](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/setpixel-apply-alternative.66532/) the source thread where I gathered my information if you are interested in it for more details. Kudos for the Unity community.

Comment: For a first one, I used `SetPixels` but almost nothing change rather than `SetPixel`. As you see in that thread, first of all I find pixel that is touched or clicked then assume a circle with 20 radius I change all the pixels in the circle. So if I want to use `SetPixels` I need to find indices of array of colors and then change colors value to alpha = 0 then send it to the `SetPixels` method. For a second one, I use `Apply` out of loop so there isn't any problems. For a third one, I use 256 * 256 sprite and FPS is on 40 and I think it's not good. So if there is any problems let me know.

Comment: and I have a question, is it good to use for instance sixteen 256 * 256 sprite instead of one 1024 *1024 ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Yeah, if you can slice your bigger textures to smaller ones that's a great idea. If you still need the 60 FPS however you may try [this method](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/super-fast-method-to-create-1-texture-from-multiple-textures.66179/#post-1176312) in the thread or look up the native [OpenGL commands](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html). I'm not that of an expert on those however. Never really needed 'em before but they are way faster than SetPixels() and Apply() because they are low-level instructions.